# unable to get content from js object

Tags: javascript, html

I am using `onclick="updatePost('{{ data }}')"` to pass list in my JavaScript file,  on `console.log(data);`in JavaScript it gives me `{name: "[object Object],[object Object]"}` I am not able to get my data and I am sure that I am missing something. Thank you for your help. ;)

data looks as JSON:

```
{
  "post": [
    {
      "location": {
        "coordinates": [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        "state": "",
        "country": ""
      },
      "content": {
        "service": "",
        "description": ""
      },
      "properties": {
        "created_on": "",
        "status": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: post more code, please

Comment: @KarlL That is not true, you can pass any JS variable.

Comment: Try `onclick="updatePost(data)"`

Comment: you might need to stringify your object, depends on how you are rendering the the HTML